# Should uploaded images be stored on the server or react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I using react and node.js/mongodb. I have a form on the frontend for uploading images via React. Currently I store the image name in mongo db and upload the image to the server (an img folder in my node.js project). Is that the correct way to do it or should I store the image name in the database and upload the image to my img folder in my react project instead of the node server?

Comment: Image on server is alright, shouldn't be in your React project. But usually we have another static file server for images and files uploaded by user. Two common options are AWS s3 and google cloud storage. Having user uploaded content on the server that executes code (ie. node server in this case) might give an attacker a chance to  upload some file that looks like an image but is some code which can run on your server and get access to your website, unlikely but can happen, why take the chance. Also static servers like S3 etc cost a lot less compared to servers than can run node.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to have to pay for a service which is why I think I will have to upload to the node.js server. Well, the node.js project is deployed to Heroku so that is effectively where I am uploading the images to

Comment: AWS S3 is free for one year, to a certain limit of usage, but that would be more than enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your projects' needs, but in general one should not store images in a react project neither should one keep them on the node server.

The way I do it is to upload my images to a cloud storage such as Microsoft Azure storage or AWS S3 and store the image URL in a (mongodb) database.

This ensures that your images are persisted even when your server is wiped or restored.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to have to pay for a service which is why I think I will have to upload to the node.js server. Well, the node.js project is deployed to Heroku so that is effectively where I am uploading the images to

Comment: That won't work, I had the same setup and realized that my uploaded images disappeared every day I looked around and figured out that Heroku restarts your server every day to the last deployed state (which means any uploaded images uploaded through your website, excluding the assets folder in your website that you upload when deploying) will get lost. See this link for reference https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Not sure how many images you plan to upload and store but I have some images on azure and my average monthly bill is about 30 US cents.

Comment: Do you have a link to azure where I can check it out?

Comment: This is a link to azure blob storage https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/ and this is a link on how to use it with nodeJS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs It will require some learning but I found it really worthwhile.